# Blur, Big picture on wordpress product description page

Tags: wordpress, lazy-loading

I was using WP Rocket for speeding my wordpress store and I don't know sometimes why the pictures at product description page shows like the image that I have added and sometimes it shows as expected like small images.
I tried to change settings but yeah still not make any different. Can somebody help me with this matter?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: disable wp-rocket, refresh your browser cache (control+f5) and try if it's behaviour

Comment: Thank you, i’ll do that but i do want to use wp-rocket because I saw a change in speed on my website after I started using wp-rocket. Do you have anything to suggest for this situation?